# Partial application of Scala macros

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, type-parameter

The example illustrating the problem:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Test {
  def foo1[A, B]: Unit = macro impl[A, B]
  def foo2[A]: Unit = macro impl[A, Option[Int]]

  def impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag, B: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    c.echo(c.enclosingPosition, s"A=${weakTypeOf[A]}, B=${weakTypeOf[B]}")
    reify(())
  }
}

/*
scala> Test.foo1[Int, Option[Int]]
<console>:12: A=Int, B=Option[Int]
       Test.foo1[Int, Option[Int]]
                ^
scala> Test.foo2[Int]
<console>:12: A=Int, B=Option[A] // <--- Expected: A=Int, B=Option[Int]
       Test.foo2[Int]
*/
```

Why did we lost the concrete type in `foo2`? It looks very similar to `foo1`.

PS: I've found a solution which could be not the best:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

object Test {
  def foo1[A, B](implicit bTag: TypeTag[B]): Unit = macro impl[A, B]
  def foo2[A](implicit bTag: TypeTag[Option[Int]]): Unit = macro impl[A, Option[Int]]

  def impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag, B](c: blackbox.Context)(bTag: c.Expr[TypeTag[B]]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    c.echo(c.enclosingPosition, s"A=${weakTypeOf[A]}, B=${bTag.actualType.typeArgs.head}")
    reify(())
  }
}

/*
scala> Test.foo1[Int, Option[Int]]
<console>:12: A=Int, B=Option[Int]
       Test.foo1[Int, Option[Int]]
                ^

scala> Test.foo2[Int]
<console>:12: A=Int, B=Option[Int]
       Test.foo2[Int]
*/
```

But an answer for the question is still interesting to me.

Answer (score 0):

type Lambda

```
def foo2[A]: Unit = macro impl[A, {type A = Option[Int]}]

def impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag, B: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe._
  //Option[Int]
  println(c.weakTypeOf[B].members.find(_.isType).get.typeSignature)
  reify(())
}
```